# NFC intent is not catched on some android devices

Tags: android-intent, nfc

I am creating app to write data to tag. A have not added any intent filters, because application doesnt have to be fired on Tag discovered intent. 
The main problem is that it works fine on Note3, but on SGS4 some default apps are opened and app doesnt catch NFC intent. 
Here is my sample code:

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) 
{
    Tag discoveredTag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    writeSomeStuffToTag(discoveredTag);
}   
}

private void writeSomeStuffToTag(Tag tag) throws IOException,FormatException {
    Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tag);
    int size =  Integer.parseInt(tagSize.getText().toString());
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * size];
    NdefRecord dataToWrite = NdefRecord.createMime("Application/com.android.nfctest", bytes);
    ndefTag.connect();
    ndefTag.writeNdefMessage(new NdefMessage(dataToWrite));
    ndefTag.close();
    }
```

And my xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nfctest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I assume you registered for foreground dispatch. The relevant part that might cause the differences in behavior between your devices is most likely how you registered for the foreground dispatch. So you would need to show us that part of your code too.

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to know what tag you are using and what the "default apps" are that are opened instead of your app receiving the intent.

Comment: Actually, this is most of my code. I havent registered foreground dispatch, but i found some thing.
I see that there is Tags app on both devices, but on Note3 it takes 0 bytes, but on S4 it takes some 200KB. So on Note3 this Tags app may not be working, so it doesnt take NFC intent

My tag is Mifare type 4 NDEF formatted

Comment: well, if you didn' register for foreground dispatch AND didn't register any NFC-related intent filters in your manifest, how would you expect your app to get notified upon any NFC intents. If that really were the case, you app won't receive the TAG_DISCOVERED intent in onNewIntent on any platform.

Comment: But it did :)
I figured this all out. Of course i was needing dispatch and filters. Thanks Michael

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect NFC events (except for those triggered by Android Application Records), you need to register for those intents. You can do this either via the manifest (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#filtering-intents)) or through the foreground dispatch system (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch)).